# Digest algorithm for the PRNG in OpenVPN

Tags: hash, vpn, random, entropy, openvpn

Considering the following OpenVPN (2.4) option from [the manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage):

```
--prng alg [nsl]
(Advanced) For PRNG (Pseudo-random number generator), use digest algorithm alg (default=sha1), and set nsl (default=16) to the size in bytes of the nonce secret length (between 16 and 64).
Set alg=none to disable the PRNG and use the OpenSSL RAND_bytes function instead for all of OpenVPN's pseudo-random number needs.
```

How much would the entropy of the prng be increased by a more secure hashing algorithm, say `SHA512`?

Also, what exactly is the `nonce secret length` and how does it impact the entropy?